# How to restrict table results with linq statement, based on its "Status"

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq statement that pulls results from my databse. What i want to try and do is display everything except those rows with a campaign status of Archived

```
MSCDatabaseDataContext MSCDB = new MSCDatabaseDataContext();
            var q = from row in MSCDB.Tbl_Campaigns
                    select new Campaign

                    {   
                        CampaignID = row.CampaignId,
                        CampaignName = row.CampaignName,
                        Target = Convert.ToInt32(row.Target),
                        Discount = Convert.ToInt32(row.Discount),
                        CampaignStartDatesS = Convert.ToDateTime(row.StartDate).Date + " - " + Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndDate).Date,
                        //CampaignSDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.StartDate),
                        //CampaignEDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndDate),
                        CurrentStatus = row.EndDate >= DateTime.Now && row.StartDate <= DateTime.Now ? "Active": row.StartDate >=  DateTime.Now ? "Pending": row.CampaignStatus == 4 ? "Archived": "Closed",
                        Uptake = Convert.ToInt32(row.Uptake),
                    };
```

The way i determine if a campaign is archived is based on its campaign status, which is 4. Ive been rattling my head with this for a while. Is there someone who could help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be extremely close. Just use a `where` clause:

```
var q = from row in MSCDB.Tbl_Campaigns
        where row.CampaignStatus != 4
        select new Campaign
        {
            ...
        };
```

Comment: Thanks dude. Please let me know when its okay to kiss you.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
 MSCDatabaseDataContext MSCDB = new MSCDatabaseDataContext();
                var q = from row in MSCDB.Tbl_Campaigns
                        where row.status != 'Archived'
                        select new Campaign

                        {   
                            CampaignID = row.CampaignId,
                            CampaignName = row.CampaignName,
                            Target = Convert.ToInt32(row.Target),
                            Discount = Convert.ToInt32(row.Discount),
                            CampaignStartDatesS = Convert.ToDateTime(row.StartDate).Date + " - " + Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndDate).Date,
                            //CampaignSDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.StartDate),
                            //CampaignEDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndDate),
                            CurrentStatus = row.EndDate >= DateTime.Now && row.StartDate <= DateTime.Now ? "Active": row.StartDate >=  DateTime.Now ? "Pending": row.CampaignStatus == 4 ? "Archived": "Closed",
                            Uptake = Convert.ToInt32(row.Uptake),
                        };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, the other guy also just answered that. Not sure how i missed this xD

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a where clause to that:

```
MSCDatabaseDataContext MSCDB = new MSCDatabaseDataContext();
        var q = from row in MSCDB.Tbl_Campaigns
                where row.CampaignStatus != 4
                select new Campaign

                {   
                    CampaignID = row.CampaignId,
                    CampaignName = row.CampaignName,
                    Target = Convert.ToInt32(row.Target),
                    Discount = Convert.ToInt32(row.Discount),
                    CampaignStartDatesS = Convert.ToDateTime(row.StartDate).Date + " - " + Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndDate).Date,
                    //CampaignSDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.StartDate),
                    //CampaignEDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndDate),
                    CurrentStatus = row.EndDate >= DateTime.Now && row.StartDate <= DateTime.Now ? "Active": row.StartDate >=  DateTime.Now ? "Pending": row.CampaignStatus == 4 ? "Archived": "Closed",
                    Uptake = Convert.ToInt32(row.Uptake),
                };
```